# Google Custom Search sort attribute issue

Tags: google-search-api, google-custom-search

I am having problems using the sort attribute within my GCS request. Whenever I use sort targeting a PageMap element it returns with 0 results. Check it out below. Am I simply missing or misunderstanding something?

Request Without Sort:
http://www.google.com/cse?cx=010537259921960391009:s7pan_vavqu&output=xml_no_dtd&q=fire+more:pagemap:course

Request With Sort:
http://www.google.com/cse?cx=010537259921960391009:s7pan_vavqu&output=xml_no_dtd&q=fire+more:pagemap:course&sort=course-coursenumber:a

Answer (score 1):

you probably didn't enable the sort option. read how to do so in:
http://support.google.com/customsearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2549537